# How to adjust a path to avoid collisions with moving obstacles inside a nav mesh?

Tags: ai, path-finding, navmesh, collision-avoidance, collision-prediction

I'm writing a script for a bot and I'm a little bit stuck.

There's a game, there's a player (me) and I want to get from point A to point B.

I can find the path via bot's API (it returns a `List<Vector3F>` points).

There's also an NPC who wanders along a known route (also `List<Vector3F>`), back and forth. Actually there're several NPCs with their own predefined routes.

How can I **adjust my path to not collide with these NPCs** (which are themselves moving)?

I've read a bit about pathfinding, collision avoidance, velocity obstacles, WHCA*, HRVO, but I can't figure out what's the best in my situation.

The problem is that these algorithms can give me points which lie outside of nav mesh (I think so)...

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: "I think so" - you *think*, or you have a reproducible test case that demonstrates this problem in a way we can help you troubleshoot and fix?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't have it yet, I'm working on it.. but since I don't have direct access to the nav mesh, I can suggest that some new points (of the adjusted path) can be outside of it.. I can add obstacles though and ask the API to recalculate the path.. The question is how to properly add and remove these obstacles in a 4-dimensional spatio-temporal space

Comment: Your navmesh API doesn't expose a "get closest point on navmesh" or "is point on navmesh" query?

Comment: @DMGregory there're queries like "is point on navmesh", "add obstacle", "remove obstacle", "get path"

Comment: I think I can trace the position of the NPCs into the future as well as my position, and if I get close to the NPCs in some moment in the future, I can add obstacles (before actually walking along the path).. and ask the API to recalculate the path

Comment: That sounds like a strategy worth testing, and posting as an Answer below if it works for you.